# Get position along electric wire

Tags: measurement, electrical, copper

Do you know the game called [Buzzwire](http://www.miniscience.com/projects/BUZZWIRE/index.html) where the aim is to guide the grip mounted loop through the wire maze without touching the loop against the metal maze all the way to the end? is it possible to get the position of the "wand" along the metal maze at any given moment and also detect where a "touch" event happen?

Specific question: what method/system/strategy should I use to get the x coordinate position of the wand (see picture) along the wire at any given moment into an arduino device or similar?

The idea is to use the device as "game controller" and move a character on a screen based on how fast the player is moving the wand along the wire

[image]

Comment: This would be more difficult by far than it's worth, though it is possible.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Keep in mind that *"Is it possible ...?"* is a yes/no question. In this case, the answer is "Yes". If you're asking us to design it for you, that would be too broad. You would need to specify something about the level of performance you expect as well as what constraints you have on the implementation. What is your specific question?

Comment: @Hearth You could visualize it as a rheostat and then use an op-amp to amplify and offset the voltage across the wire. Not too difficult, but it requires the wire having same resistance to the other contactor everywhere (good luck with that). + This is screaming XY problem. Hey OP, why don't you tell us what you are **actually** trying to do instead of giving us a **weird** example that you think is going to help you?

Comment: I drew this but the question was closed before I could post. http://i.stack.imgur.com/W9qTm.png. (a) A constant current source. (b) Using a lamp as a constant current source.*

If you have access to a lab power supply with a 1 or 3 A capability try figure 1a. If not try 1b. You'll need a sensitive voltmeter.

Comment: By the way, it's "20 cm" (with a space), not "20cmts".

Comment: @hearth I have modified the question and the picture to make it more concise

Comment: like @Hearth wrote it should be possible but a lot of work.  If you just want the position at time of contact you can use a non-oxidising resistive wire (stainless steel) with a decent current flowing through it.  To measure without contact you may have to use some sensitive time domain reflectometry or perhaps capacitively coupled stepped frequency standing wave detection that will detect which modes it is near at many frequencies that are transmitted into the transmission line.

Comment: thanks @KalleMP , still not sure why this question was put on hold after just few seconds of being published and now that I edited it and clearly people is understanding it, it is still on hold after an hour

Comment: @Delcasda  There is an undercurrent of over moderation on some of the stacks and if it does not conform to the letter of the policy statement then is runs foul of well (and not so well) meaning moderators who want to preserve the purity of the stacks thinking that a few questions that may never be seen again will contaminate all the divine advice that the contributors have given to the SE overlords for free.  My policy is that disk space is cheap and if long standing members do not want to answer stupid questions they could just skip them and let the newbies cut their teeth on them.

Comment: @KalleMP actually that is a very precise description of the feeling I am getting here. So they just put on hold but never care of unhold after editing it? I wonder if this kind of question can not be posted here, where could it be?